# How to create and insert to a custom table in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

The question is clear from the title itself , what i need is creating a `customer_token` table and insert data to it upon registration ,

here is

**what i have tried**

in `my_project/app/core/code/Mage/Customer/sql/mysql4-install-0.7.0`

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{$this->getTable('customer_token')}`;
CREATE TABLE `{$this->getTable('customer_token')}` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `customer_id` smallint(8) unsigned  default '0',
  `token` varchar(255)   default '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `expire_at` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In `my_project/app/core/code/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml`

```
<entities>
     <customer_token>
        <table>customer_token</table>
    </customer_token>
</entities>
```

In `my_project/app/core/code/Mage/Customer/Resource/token.php`

```
class Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Token extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract
{


}
```

And in  `my_project/wrappers/customer_register.php`

```
  $token = getToken(20);
        $data = array('customer_id' => 1, 'token' => $token);
        $model = Mage::getModel('customer/token')->setData($data);
        try {
            $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
            echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: " . $insertId;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

But it throws me a `Resource is not set` error . Any idea ??

**UPDATE**

I followed the blog specified in the answer and created a module as

customer_token  . am sharing the main files below ,

```
 `my_project\app\code\community\Customer\Token\etc\config.xml`
```

1.0.0
        
    
    
        
            
                Customer_Token_Model
                customertoken_resource
            
            
                Customer_Token_Model_Resource
                
                    
                        customer_token
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    Customer_Token
                
                
                    core_setup
                
            
            
                
                    core_read
                
            
            
                
                    core_write
                
            
        
        
        
            
                Customer_Token_Block

```
<!-- start of routers 
-->
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customertoken>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Customer_Token</module>
                <frontName>customertoken</frontName>
            </args>
        </customertoken>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <customertoken>
                <file>customertoken.xml</file>
            </customertoken>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

IN   `my_project\app\code\community\Customer\Token\Model\Customertoken.php`

```
   class Cusotmer_Token_Model_Customertoken extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('customertoken/customertoken');
    }

}
```

And in `my_project\app\etc\modules\Customer_Token.xml`

```
    <config>
     <modules>
        <Customer_Token>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Customer_Token>
    </modules>
   </config>
```

And in `my_project\app\code\community\Customer\Token\Resource\Collection.php`

```
class Cusotmer_Token_Model_Resource_Customertoken_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {

    protected function _constuct() {
        $this->_init('customertoken/customertoken');
    }

}
```

And in `my_project\app\code\community\Customer\Token\Resource\Customertoken.php`

```
class Customer_Token_Model_Resource_Customertoken extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('customertoken/customertoken', 'id');
    }
}
```

And in `my_project\app\code\community\Customer\Token\sql\customertoken_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php`

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{$this->getTable('customer_token')}`;
CREATE TABLE `{$this->getTable('customer_token')}` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `customer_id` smallint(8) unsigned  default '0',
  `token` varchar(255)   default '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `expire_at` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");
$installer->endSetup();
```

And am calling it like this ,

```
$data = array('customer_id' => $customerId, 'token' => $token);
    $model = Mage::getModel('customer_token/custmertoken')->addData($data);
    try {
        $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
        echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: " . $insertId;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I appreciate your help , thanks .

Answer (score 9):

**There are lot of issue in your module.**

### Don't create any custom table on Core_Module

It is `too bad idea` to create a `model` at  Core Module(Mage_Customer) and it `break magento standard`.

I suggest you need to  `define model at a new custom module`.

Please the [blog](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/)  how create Model of table.

### Model and resource model class was not write properly

If you  are using `custom Module` and using `flat table format` for that Model
then

**Model** class inherit from   `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.

**Resource Model** class inherit from   `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`.

**Collection Model** class inherit from  `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`.

### Insert data;

As you have set multiple fields ,so you need to `use addData()` function.

Also you can `$id value after model save data`. Basically give the table primary key.

If you define custom module then it config.xml look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
    <!-- Model is define at here -->
            <custommodule> <!-- Model Prefix -->
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>custommodule_resource</resourceModel>
            </custommodule>
    <!--  Resource Model is define at here -->

            <custommodule_resource>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <token> <!-- define an new  entities for module -->
                        <table>customer_token</table> <!-- define table -->
                    </token>
                </entities>
            </custommodule_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <custommodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </custommodule_setup>
            <custommodule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </custommodule_read>
            <custommodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </custommodule_write>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Model class is like :**
Model file Token.php path is app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Token extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/token');
    }

}
```

**ResourceModel**:

Resource class  `Token.php`

```
app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model/Resource/

<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource_Token extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/token', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Data save Like :**

```
$token = getToken(20);
$data = array('customer_id' => 1, 'token' => $token);
$model = Mage::getModel('custommodule/token')->addData($data);
try {
$model->save(); //save data 
    $insertId = $model->getId();
    echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: " . $insertId;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: okay let me try this way

Comment: the link of blog is not proper

Comment: see  i have  update link

Comment: It throws me a Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object Error

Comment: is addData() is works

Comment: No it also not working , i will share the whole code structure on upadte

Comment: Is it because any wrong in calling the module Or in XML ?

Comment: If you have any clue ,pls help me

Comment: What if a table has no model, like directory_country_region_name ?