# add data in database dynamically

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add data in database from front end using modules. So I created a form as given below:

```
<form>
 <div id="form_div">
  <label>Title</label>
  <input id="title" type="text" name="" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>File Name</label>
  <input id="file_name" type="text" name="" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>Content</label>
  <input id="content" type="text" name="" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>Status</label>
  <input id="status" type="text" name="" />
  <br /><br />
  <input id="add_button" type="submit" value="Add" />
 </div>
</form>
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I insert data from frontend in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a action url in your form as shown below :

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('modulefrontname/index/save'); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="form-validate-payment" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
  <div id="form_div">
  <label>Title</label>
  <input id="title" type="text" name="title" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>File Name</label>
  <input type="file" id="file_name" type="text" name="file_name" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>Content</label>
  <input id="content" type="text" name="content" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>Status</label>
  <input id="status" type="text" name="status" />
  <br /><br />
  <input id="add_button" type="submit" value="Add" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Then create save action in indexController as shown below:

```
public function SaveAction() {
   $postdata = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

   if($postdata){

       if (isset($_FILES['file_name']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name']))) {
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('file_name');
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS;
        $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['file_name']['name']);
        $filename = $_FILES['file_name']['name'];
        }
       $model = Mage::getModel("test/test");
       $model->setData($postdata);
       $model->setFileName($filename);
       $model->save();
   }
   $this->loadLayout();
   $this->renderLayout()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. but in my case a new row is getting added but the data inside the table is not getting added.

Comment: ok i got it, it worked. I forgot to add the name attribute. Thanks a lot @Prasanta Hatui

Answer (score 1):

Create `saveAction()` in your controller, in that`saveAction()`  put this code.

```
 $model = Mage::getModel('test/test');
 $data = array('dbfeildname1'=>$data1,'dbfeildname2'=>$data2);
 $model->setData($data);
 $model->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But I want to add data when I click on submit button. How can I fire that?

Comment: @Birju do you know how to create controller in magento ?

Comment: yes i have created a controller already where I have defined a function for delete before

Comment: @Birju create saveAction() in controller for saveAction() and put this code in saveAction()

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following steps to save data to dramatically.

1. Register Module and Activate Module
2. Create Controller
3. Create Configuration XML
4. Create Helper Class
5. Create Models
6. SQL Setup
7. Template Design
8. Blocks

You may be help the following article
[How to create and insert to a custom table in magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63142/how-to-create-and-insert-to-a-custom-table-in-magento)